# Send/Receive SMS Messages Through the Gmail SMS Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, sms, gmail

I am trying to send/receive SMS messages through the Gmail SMS [plugin](http://www.google.com/mobile/sms/mail/) with Java, but I am not sure which Gmail Java client library would be best for this. I have hear of `g4j` and the `google-java-client-api` but I am not sure those are suitable. I have hear of the method of where you can send an SMS through SMTP, *but* you need to know the recipient's carrier's SMTP server, which is a little complicated since I would like to send an SMS to a phone number without knowing the carrier of the recipient. Any suggestions? Thanks!